# C++ Having trouble using std::find() to locate a string within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, find

for a homework project I'm required to locate a string from an array. Now I've been trying to make the function work for the past hour and I'm just getting myself more confused. I'm pretty sure find() returns the address of where it found your value. What am i doing wrong here!?

Code below:

**Class Member Method:**

```
bool ArrayStorage::stdExists(string word)
{
    if (arrayOfWords != NULL)
    {
        size_t findResult = find(&arrayOfWords[0], &arrayOfWords[arrayLength], word);
        std::cout << "word found at: " << findResult << '\n';
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

**(string word) from main:**

```
string find = "pixel";
```

**Member method that declares array:**

```
void ArrayStorage::read(ifstream &fin1)
{
    int index = 0;
    int arrayLength = 0;
    string firstWord;

    if(fin1.is_open())
        {
            fin1 >> firstWord;
            fin1 >> arrayLength;
            setArrayLength(arrayLength);

            arrayOfWords = new string[arrayLength];

            while(!fin1.eof())
            {
                fin1 >> arrayOfWords[index];
                index++;
            }
        }
}
```

**Header File:**

```
class ArrayStorage
{

private:

    string* arrayOfWords;
    int arrayLength;
    int value;

public:

    void read(ifstream &fin1); //reads data from a file
    void write(ofstream &out1); //output data to an output stream(ostream)
    bool exists(string word); //return true or false depending whether or not a given word exists
    bool stdExists(string word); //^^ use either std::count() or std::find() inside here

    //setters
    void setArrayLength(int value);

    //getters
    int getArrayLength();

    ArrayStorage::ArrayStorage() : arrayOfWords(NULL)
    {
    }

    ArrayStorage::~ArrayStorage()
    {
        if (arrayOfWords)
        delete []arrayOfWords;
    }

};
```

Comment: How is `arrayOfWords` declared?

Comment: `&arrayOfWords[arrayLength]` looks suspicious. Something like `std::begin(arrayOfWords)` and `std::end(arrayOfWords)` is unambiguous here.

Comment: @chris It's your good ole past the end pointer, why is it suspicious?

Comment: `arrayOfWords` is declared as an array of string pointers in a header file, and values are sent to it via creation of a dynamic array in a separate member method in the same class declaration. Haven't had any problems passing in values of `arrayOfWords` in my other methods, array works fine.

Comment: @chris begin and end will only work if arrayOfWords is really an array and not a pointer. You can't tell the difference from this code.

Comment: So, what exactly is a problem? Compilation error, runtime error, wrong result?

Comment: @pmr, Good point, I forgot about pointers other than the parameter list, and it isn't in there.

Comment: "IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::find" matches the argument list"

Comment: @jrok, More that it dereferences it before taking the address.

Comment: @chris I see what's bugging you. But that's well defined to be exactly the same as `*(a + length)`.

Comment: code added for clarification.

Comment: Avoid `using namespace std;`.  Avoid manually managing a buffer, just use `std::vector` instead.  When you have a problem you don't understand, you should not post just the line that causes the problem.  Nor should you copy all of your code.  Instead, create a self contained, simple, short (almost) compiling example of your problem.  Read this http://sscce.org/ for future reference.  And on SO, etiquette is that you don't say "Thanks in advance" or the like.

Comment: Hi Yakk. Was it you who marked down my question for your reasoning's above?

Comment: Assuming it was, this is my fourth question on SO. I joined two days ago. I make the effort to format my question's and to be honest I was only inquiring about a small problem in relation to one function. I am about five days in to learning C++, if I had the ability to confidently post another code snippet that mirrored my problem I would. However that would require me having at least a good understanding of the problem in front of me, defeating the point of this question. Secondly, I made sure to thank those who helped, "thanks in advance" was merely a pleasantry. No need for punishment here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

g++ does not even compile this code, with the precise error message:

error: invalid conversion from 'std::basic_string*' to 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]

so, you need to change the code to:

```
string* findResult = find(&arrayOfWords[0], &arrayOfWords[arrayLength], word);
```

if this pointer is equal to &arrayOfWords[arrayLength], no match is found.

Comment: Absolute boss mate you killed it! Thanks a lot I understand the reasoning now as well.

Comment: Another thing: Probably bool stdExists(const string& word) const; would be better style (pass argument by const reference is likely to be more efficient, const method for const correctness)

Comment: Ill make sure to take note! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

find does not return an address, but an iterator of the same type as the arguments. Which is a pointer to whatever type is stored inside arrayOfWords.

Responding to your comment: if arrayOfWords contains pointers to strings you need to use find_if because operator== cannot compare a pointer to something with a something.

Comment: If it were a requirement for me to actually use find and not find_if, would it be a long process for me to rejig my code to suit?

Comment: Given that the code you accepted, your comment was wrong. You have an array of strings and not an array of pointers to strings...